# How to Write a Composable AJAX Call in Polymer

Tags: ajax, polymer-2.x, dom-repeat

I am trying to write a component that exposes the data from an AJAX call in Polymer.  I would like to end with something like.

```
<get-db data={{data}}></get-db>

<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
    <div>{{item}}</div>
</template>
```

However, when I expose the `data` property from `get-db` component in another element, the data doesn't bind to the `dom-repeat` template.

> The get-db component parts are as follows

```
<iron-ajax id="ajax"
  url="https://api/endpoint"
  method="post"
  handle-as="json"
  content-type="application/json"
  body="[[request]]"
  last-response="{{response}}"></iron-ajax>
```

...

```
  static get properties() {
    return {

      response: Object,

      request: Object,

      username: String,

      data: Object

    }
  }

  getResponse() {
    if (this.username && this.apiKey) {
      this.request = {
        "body": "bodyText"
      };
      let request = this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
      request.completes.then(req => {
        this.setResponse();
      })
      .catch(rejected => {
        console.log(rejected.request);
        console.log(rejected.error);
      })
    }
  }

  setResponse() {
    if(this.response[0]) {
      this.data = this.response[0];
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The data property needs to be set to notify.

```
 data: {
   type: Object,
   notify: true
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add notify but also you need to use `this.set` method in order to get observable changes for `data` properties. Also you are setting only one item to `data` properties (assuming you have a array at `response` properties.) I guess you need all array instead only `0. index` as you are looping in dom-repeat. That's why this below code may help:

```
static get properties() {
    return {

      response:{
         type:Object,
         observer:'checkResponce'},

      request: Object,

      username: String,

      data: {
         type:Array,
         notify:true}

    }
  }
 static get observers() { return [ 'checkUserNApi(username,apiKey)']}

  checkUserNApi(u,a){
      if (u && a) this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
  }
  checkResponce(d) {
      if (d) {
          this.set('data',d); //with this method data property at parent will change upon you received responce
      }  
  }
```

Finally, you may add to `iron-ajax`  a line `check error on-error="{{error}}"` if you want to see an error report.

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/cappittall/pen/oEwXxy)

Comment: When I use this in a parent component, the ajax call doesn't fire until the page is navigated to then changed.

Comment: Also, putting an observer on the AJAX call creates an infinite loop.

Comment: Ajax call will fire when you have defined `username` and `àpiKey` as you wanted to check these properties in your code (I don't know where those are coming). So, I added an observer to see defined or not.

Comment: When you fired `ajax` you will receive a response once in `response` property. Then if it is contain data, you transfer this data to `data` property with `set` method.